# SQL ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"Position: 43

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, syntax-error

I'm making a Java program that generates random data and populates a PostgreSQL Database. I'm at the beginning of my program and the following code is actually the part adding a row (not generated randomly) to the table public.bank_card_people . The columns of the table are first-name, last-name and card-number. The connection with database is effective as I achieve to print rows from the table.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Benerator","postgres","newPassword");
        String SQL = "insert into public.bank_card_people (first-name, last-name, card-number) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        stmt2.setString(1, "ra");
        stmt2.setString(2, "ra");
        stmt2.setString(3, "ra");
        stmt2.executeQuery();
```

I ran the program and had the error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"Position: 43`

I will keep you updated if I find a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PostgreSQL use "first-name" around your field

So the SQL would be

```
String SQL = "insert into public.bank_card_people (\"first-name\", \"last-name\", \"card-number\") VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!

So I put the "-" back in the columns names and replaced the line in my code with 

> String SQL = "insert into public.bank_card_people (`first-name`, `last-name`, `card-number`) VALUES (?,?,?)";

However I had the error 
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
> Position: 38

Comment: Backticks are MySQL specific, the SQL standard defines double quotes for quoting object names, and like most database systems, that is what PostgreSQL does. You may want to consider editing your question to remove this MySQL specific behavior as it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Removed

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, gave it a try and that works perfectly

Comment: @Lancek I am glad it's helpful. Please upvote / accept as an answer for future users.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question since I achieved to make my program work, I hope it will help some of you.

Actually, the problem was simple, I just changed the names of the columns in the public.bank_card_people , as SQL didn't seem to like it. I basically removed the "-" so for example first-name would become firstname and last-name would become lastname.

Comment: This is not the solution, it's workaround. Changing in the database is an expensive operation and it's not a good idea, you could use &#96; in your java code's field name

Comment: @DebmalyaBiswas On the other hand, if this is a new database, then it actually is the 'right' solution. Avoiding the need to quote object names should - in my opinion - be preferred.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I agree on the part from the first time we should follow the right path. This solution, of course, an option for the new database. BUT to "fix the Java code we change in the database field's name" is still doesn't sound right. So I considered this as workaround.